# What are the cons of importing only the application related schema (s) and leaving Oracle metadata (SYS, SYSTEM etc) out when migrating a database

Tags: export, schema

I'd like to migrate a database of an app that has a single schema (say S) storing the app data. Is there anything against only exporting S and importing it to a new, 'empty' instance?

The source database is 12c, and the destination is 18 and 19.

I have quite a number of errors when doing a full db expdb/impdb and I have only one warning when doing a migration on schema level excluding every schema from the export but the one that is used by the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Migrating a single schema is normal, and migrating SYS/SYSTEM to a different version of Oracle is likely to cause problems, because part of the upgrade is changing the dictionary tables in those schemas.